# OrientDB.NET driver, how to get @fieldTypes

Tags: c#, orientdb

I have succeeded at connecting and retrieving almost all desired properties of my test class but .NET binary driver seems to have an issue with `@fieldTypes` string.

Here is what I have done so far to try and debug retrieved values:

```
document = db.Query("select from interventi limit 10");


                foreach (ODocument singleDoc in document)
                {
                    List<ORID> orids = singleDoc.GetField<List<ORID>>("out_InterventoICD");
                    foreach(ORID rid in orids)
                    {
                        lblResults.Text += rid.ToString() + ",";
                    }
                    lblResults.Text += "<br />";

                    string relationTypes =  singleDoc.GetField<string>("@fieldTypes");

                    lblResults.Text += relationTypes;

                }
```

If I use `REST` protocol I can retrieve the list of fields with related type correctly but the binary driver instead seems to not return any value.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you using https://github.com/orientechnologies/OrientDB-NET.binary
if you are then open issue and i will help you with your case

Comment: Thanks, Roman. I have opened an issue as you recommended. in the meantime I have verified that there is no provision anywhere in the client's code to manage @fieldTypes and neither there is a specific property in Document.cs class